# Mini Split Condenser in Garage? With ventilation?

Tags: air-conditioning, exhaust-fan, mini-split, intake-fan

I live in a fairly warm and dry environment and due to HOA restrictions am unable to place a window A/C unit, outdoor unit, or a system on the roof. I understand that A/C shouldn't go in attics due to the heat.

However, I was wondering if an A/C unit could go into a garage that had an exhaust / intake fan cut into the side of the wall. This air flow could even be directed into a self contained box which the condenser portion is in.

Is such an installation feasible? If so, how do I calculate what amount of CFMs the fans will need to push to sufficiently cool the a/c unit?

Is it correct that a 1 ton A/C system passes about 400CFM per minute? If my garage is 5000 Cubic feet (25x25x8), then it would take about 12minutes to cycle through all the air. Thus I would need exhaust and intake fans that can push 400CFM?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a single-family dwelling, or a condominium of some sort? Have you asked the HOA how they're *expecting* air conditioning to be provisioned, or if they are trying to forbid A/C altogether?

Comment: Also, 400CFM/ton is the *indoor blower* airflow rate, not the *condenser fan* airflow rate...

Comment: It is a condominium constructed in townhome fashion, with separate entrance. The HOA allows A/C for units that have patios or carports since those count as restricted area, neither of which I have. I simply have a garage. A/C is allowed at other units that have the features mentioned above, so they do not prohibit A/C. An old board also grandfathered in a unit that has a condenser in the common area but no longer allows this.

Comment: How does one find the consender fan airflow rate?

Comment: Do you have a neighbor within piping distance who has a "restricted space"?

Comment: This restriction is amazing because the modern mini-split a/c units are very quiet. The condensing unit can be mounted on brackets on a wall or be placed on a pad on the ground. Does the HOA allow portable a/c units with one or two hoses emerging from a window?

Comment: So you have an HOA that actually forbids A/C in some units altogether?  I suggest you contact an attorney specializing in real estate.  I question the legality of such a restriction since the inability to control the climate can be life threatening.  (Yes, people die of heat stroke every year and the elderly in particular are susceptible to high temperatures.)

Comment: @Harper - One of my neighbors has a balcony that allows A/C placement but I suspect it is too far for running the A/C piping. Is there a typical limit on distance?

Comment: @The Evil Greebo, yes the HOA restricts A/C in some units, from what I read this is allowed since when I purchased the condo I agreed to live under the HOA's published rules, little did I know they were so restrictive. There is an exemption for a doctors notes under Federal Housing Laws but they just have to allow "reasonable accommodation" which is quite vague.

Comment: @JimStewart, yes they allow portable A/Cs with hoses resting against the window screen but they can't be on the outside of the window.

Comment: @Arctic speaking as a landlord, I can put anything in my lease I want, and the tenant can sign, and it can still be unenforceable.  No agreed upon contract item is valid if the law forbids it.  Thus I suggest you check.

Comment: Is this a well designed and constructed building with nice architectural details (built say 1920s or 30s) and the HOA wants to preserve the original ambiance?

Comment: @JimStewart nope it was built in the 1970s , they just want to preserve the exterior aesthetics.

Comment: Amazing that a building constructed in the 1970s wasn't designed and fitted with a/c. Where is this?

Comment: @JimStewart Southern California area

Comment: A 25x25 ft garage? You have a 2-car garage? That should be large enough to accommodate the condensing unit on the wall. How many bedrooms? What sq footage? You might want a 2-ton unit with one single fan condensing unit feeding two or three air handlers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this webpage](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/58396/Does-a-Heat-Pump-or-Air-Conditioner-Condenser-Need-to-Go-Outdoors), **"the answer is an emphatic NO."**  The page goes on to say this is because the total volume of air in an enclosed space is insufficient, including a garage with an open door as the air isn't likely to circulate enough.

From this we can deduce:

- **There is nothing in most codes preventing you from doing it.**
- If you are planning to do this, you'll need to pay very close
  attention to where your intake and exhaust air are coming from.
- If you don't design your ventilation perfectly, your system may not
  be able to cool your space

Answer (score 1):

I did it 10 years ago and it has worked well. It is only a room size unit but will work with larger sizes. It is not visible from outside except the 1/4" plastic drain hose sticking out of the garage wall. It is mounted close to the ceiling. I made a plenum with a 1/4 " fiberboard with a white plastic finish , so from in the garage you see a white box near the ceiling . The condenser draws air from in the garage, blows through the coils into the garage attic and eave. In the living space there is a normal room AC unit face ( projects from the wall about an inch.)  except it is mounted a few inches below the ceiling. It is a window unit , essentially the 2 X 4 stud wall is the "window", I added no extra brackets. It has a remote control so being so high is no problem; actually gives excellent circulation . The only problem is that I forget to clean the air filters.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be simple if allowed to install 2 louvered vents on the outside of the home in the garrage wall. Encase the system in a box with the vents use a powered fan either temp controlled or if the unit has an aux contact on the motor contactor that can turn on the fan on. This would work you just need to move the air so the unit can heat or cool.

Comment: Why wouldn't the fan in the condensing unit be all that is needed to move the air? In the simplest setup the condensing unit is inside the garage and there is a short duct which butts to and seals against the case around the fan. The air inside the garage is drawn into the intake of the condensing unit and replaced by air moving into the garage through a vent elsewhere in the wall of the garage.

Comment: The condenser is supposed to be outside without some air forced through the box it will run very hot.

Comment: I don't see the need for the condenser to be in a box--well, it would  reduce the noise. But for the first try I would just have it on a bracket on the wall of the garage. I have not examined these minisplit units. Where are the input vents in the case for the cooling air? In some pictures there are no vents on one end so that would leave the back (which would be facing into the garage) and the other end (also facing into garage but close to the wall). The opening for air into the garage could be on the same wall say 5 ft to 10 ft away, the further the better.

Comment: Jim I have installed a few of these they require full flow air, the op wanted to put the unit in a box this would require forced venting, if the garage is closed as most are natural venting of even a small unit would have the garrage extremely hot in a very short time and the unit would not be able to cool. Of all the systems I have installed one entire side is the condensing coil

Comment: I see pictures of these installed in Asia on the sides of multistory buildings and I have wondered how close the back side is to the building. In the US I have seen these units on the sides of high end mobile homes and on the sides of public school "portable" classrooms and wondered if those are special versions of the condensing unit or just the general version with a special installation kit.

Comment: Being outside with the required spacing is totally different than being outside. Jim get a hvac licence and install one since you a pear to only have opinions based on photos that may not have been installed according to the manufacturer instructions.

Comment: I am aware that I am inexperienced in the installation of these units. The only reason I am offering a speculative opinion on this is that the OP is considering the feasibility of an unconventional installation and so I think my opinion might add to the discussion.

Comment: Hi Ed, do you happen to have any more details on how to construct the box? What material? Or is a box even needed if the garage  is vented with two fans? (Intake and exhaust)

Comment: I would want a simple enclosure a 2x4 frame with plywood covering or even sheetrock that allows the mfg space around the unit the small unit I added not long ago required 18" on the fan side and a minimum of 6 on the other side there was no top or bottom clearances stated. If you have venting without an enclosure I would bring in the cold (powered) vent at the bottom of the wall and the vent to allow the heat to escape close to the ceiling or up in the eve of the roof, this would use the heat rising to get rid of it but the garage may get very warm but with the cool air supply should work

Answer (score -1):

If you are anticipating making an opening in the wall of the garage so that the hot exhaust from the condensing unit would have an unobstructed path to the outside, then in theory your idea to have the condensing unit inside the garage could work.

You would need some sort of seal to prevent hot air from the condensing unit from flowing back into the garage. You could mount the condensing unit on brackets on the wall of the garage. The opening could have a decorative grill on it that would hide the fan.

Normally the fan side of the condensing unit faces outward from an exterior wall so this might not work in practice because having that face of the condensing unit close to the inside of the wall of the garage might impede access to diagnostic ports of the unit.

The input air to the condensing unit would be from the inside the garage and there would have to have an opening for air to be admitted to the garage to replace that being pumped out.

You would still have to get permission from the HOA board to do this and they might find grounds to withhold approval. Would the HOA allow you to cut an opening in the wall of the garage?

Finally, the noise of the condensing unit would be trapped in the garage and could be very disturbing. The condensing unit is meant to be outside where the sound disperses. But modern condensing units make much less noise than formerly.

*EDIT**
You could get creative with ducting to get the hot air to the outside of the garage. The opening on the outside might be a rectangle 6 ft long by 0.5 ft high on the wall where it would not blow on passersby.

Comment: Yes, this is along the lines of what I was thinking. I will need to propose cutting the garage wall for this set-up and wanted to get my information before proceeding. I suspect this may be an easier approval than modifying the common area. With regards to the ducting, I was thinking of having the hot air exhaust at about 7 feet high, higher than anyone would walk past.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to calculate how much air flow the condenser will need to stay cool and replace the air?

Comment: No, I meant to suggest that it would be high on the wall, but my wording was confusing.